# .htaccess compulsory www and removing php extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If a person visits: **http://domain.com**, I want to redirect him to **http://www.domain.com** and if a person visits: **http://domain.com/remove.php**, I would like to redirect him to **http://www.domain.com/remove**

So basically, I want to add a *www* in the beginning of the url **if a subdomain is not being requested** and I also want the user to be redirected to a URL **without the PHP extension** in case he tries to access one. I know, how to **accept pages which don't have .php extension** but now I'm looking to a code for all the above features along with a redirection code which will redirect the user to a non PHP extension page in case he tries to visit one with the PHP extension

So, if he visits, he reaches ...

- http://www.domain.com/index.php http://www.domain.com/index
- http://domain.com/index.php http://www.domain.com/index
- http://domain.com/ http://www.domain.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
# First force the www (ignoring case)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

# And this rule rewrites the .php off the end.
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9)\.php http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Comment: I get a 500 Internal Server Error, when changing the code to suit my website. (I changed www.example.com to abc.mydomain.com and www\.example.com to abc\.mydomain.com)

Comment: Oops, I think it's because I missed escaping a `.` in the `RewriteCond`. Should hve been `!^www\.example\.com$`... Try it now.